# Is there a way to get the values used to create an instance in Python?

Tags: python

Given the following class and instantiation code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, delay):
        self.myparam = MyOtherClass(delay)
```

```
instance = MyClass(delay=2)
```

I need to get the param name (`delay`) and the value used for initialization (`2`). I'm able to get the param name doing `sig = inspect.signature(instance.__init__)`.

Note that I'm not setting `self.delay` so `vars()` is no use.

Comment: If you don't save it, there's no way to get it. It's not remembered automatically. Use `self.delay = delay` if you need it.

Comment: If you want to save a value, you store it in a variable. That's what variables do. If you don't save a value in a variable, it goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the values somewhere. Since `locals()` provides a dictionary of local variables, a general way to store the arguments used to initialize an instance might be like this:

```
def __init__(self, delay):
    self.args = locals()
    del self.args['self']
```

then running this code

```
instance = MyClass(delay=2)
print(instance.args)
```

prints

```
{'delay': 2}
```